# Orchard v.1.10 Send challenge email from workflow

Tags: orchardcms

I am using Orchard v.1.10
I have a form creating a new user using a workflow.
How do I send challenge email from the workflow?

Comment: You mean an email with some kind of unique code to make the user validate their registration?

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to this useful article from sipke http://www.ideliverable.com/blog/customizing-user-registration-and-login-with-dynamic-forms-and-workflows

which has very deep tutorial on registration using workflows